# Union vs inheritance in structures

Tags: c++, inheritance, unions

Assume I have some structures, which basically have a 'general' field, and some unique data, like:

```
struct A
{
    char type;
    int data;
};

struct B
{
    char type;
    int data[2];
};
```

And etc (I have a lot of them). So I can just make a base structure with same fields, and inherit others. I though that I can do the same thing using `union`, e.g.:

```
union AnyClass
{
    struct A _a;
    struct B _b;
    ...
};
```

I am receiving some data (which exactly fits the biggest member in `union`), so would prefer to use following syntax:

```
// to read it from buffer (I am receiving data from another PC, which stores data the same way (in the same union) as I do
char buf[sizeof(AnyClass)];
char type = buf[0]; // detect type
AnyClass inst;
memcpy(&inst, buf, sizeof(inst));
switch(type)
{
    ... // handle data according to its type
}

// if I want to create a new object, and send it, I can use
AnyClass myObj;
new (&myObj._b) B();
... // do whatever I want
```

**NOTE**: I am aware that I have to align data somehow, so both machines (received/sender) should interpretate buf correctly.

1. Can it run faster than same problem solution using `BaseStructure` and inherited others (so, I have to cast them right away), or it will be compiled to nearly the same code?
2. Is it OK to use, or it is just a poor design?
3. If there is another solution, can you explain it shortly?

Comment: "or it is just a poor design?" - certainly looks so to me - but you haven't described the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: You should consider something like _google protocol buffers_ when data should be exchanged over a network independently of the target architecture (little/big endian). Decomposing messages using manually created unions is probably a bad idea.

Comment: `static_casts` are pretty fast -- simple pointer arithmetic

Comment: Please note that _"it's undefined behavior to read from the member of the union that wasn't most recently written."_ from: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union

Comment: Standard directly states that members of the union that have identical staring fields will be mapped to the same addresses. This means that reading from other union member is possible, but with restrictions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance difference between mentioned approaches will be minor. It is a good chance that you will not notice it at all.

I would shape your classes like that:

```
class AnyClass
{
    char type;
    union
    {
        struct
        {
             int data1;
        };
        struct
        {
             int data2[2];
        };
    };

;
```

Note using anonymous structs and unions.

Why do you need the character buffer at all? Always allocate the typed structure and better define it without ctors and dectors. I do not like this line:

```
char type = buf[0]; // detect type
```

Here you directly assume the physical offset. The less assumptions about the layout of the structures you make, the better the result will be.

Comment: Note that anonymous structs are not allowed in standard C++.

Comment: C++ 14 syntax directly allows anonymous structs... Can you support your statement somehow?

Comment: Syntax may allow it, but the rules do not. See [dcl.dcl]/5: http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#5, the last sentence in particular. Or test with a compiler with extensions disabled: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a90d2b37fa8c1a94

Comment: For me your statement is weak. The quoted last statement: "In such cases, the decl-specifier-seq shall introduce...". In "such cases" - yes, but it does not say anything about other cases, i.e. when there is no identifier. Standalone nameless empty classes or enums are pointless. They are illegal. Fine, but nested nonempty classes are useful and I do not see that this case is explicitly prohibited. (in any case thanks for your comment).

Comment: I interpret the rule such that "such cases" are specifically those where init-declarator-list was omitted (the first statement). `class X{};` OK, init-declarator-list not omitted | `class {} x; ` OK, init-declarator-list was omitted, but decl-specifier-seq introduces a name (this is an unnamed class) | `class {};`  Not OK, init-declarator-list was omitted, but decl-specifier-seq did not introduce any names.

Comment: This is exactly the problem of document written in human language. Your interpretation may be right, and maybe not right. Why should rule that out? I am always thinking about ways of defining language in a stricter ways. BNF is great, but it is necessary to move forward.

Comment: I don't know why the committee chose to only support anonymous unions, but not classes. I can only guess that they didn't find them useful enough to introduce to the language. Neither were allowed in standard C - until way after C++ was standardized in C11 where both became standard.